# How to deal with pagination on Get requests?

Tags: api, loops, groovy, pagination, get

I'm creating a small script for automation, but I ran into a problem.

Suppose I use the Get API method to get results, then I want to add one to each result.

The assumption itself is not difficult:

```
def numbers = get(endpoint)

numbers.each{int number ->
  log.info(number+1)
}
```

I am having a hard time, however, figuring out the correct approach to pagination. The response limit for a query is 100. Before submitting a query, I don't know how many responses to expect. (There might be more than 100 and then I have to use pagination).

In this case, should I first determine how many results I can get, and with this knowledge only then create for loops for each "page"?

Or should I try with a while loop, and continue sending GET request, until total quantity would be < 100?

Something like:

```
bool continue = true;
int startAt = 0;

while(continue){
  def numbers = get(endpoint)
                .queryString('startAt', startAt)
  
  number.each{int number ->
    log.info(number+1)
  }
  startAt += 100;
  if(numbers.total == 100) continue = false;
}
```

For now I was using for loop, but had two different endpoints. One endpoint was showing me max results, second one details for each result. But the second one was limited to 100 results, so I counted how many loops I need by dividing total results by 100.